Xorg borderless window resizing
I would like to ask how to implement mouse drag resizing of a borderless window in Xorg. Specifically, how to change the mouse cursor to the resizeCursor style when the mouse is at the edge of the window. Thank you very much! enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry for the slow response due to the time difference. As shown in the image link above, what event is being listened to in GNOME to implement resizing a borderless window? If possible, could you provide a minimal implementation? Thank you very much!
